# Can Dwolla users have BOTH a non-profit and a for-profit fundingSource?

Tags: payment, dwolla

If so, are there additional API calls that need to be made from the one's listed in [`addFundingSource`](https://developers.dwolla.com/dev/docs/funding/add) in order to have both under a single Dwolla account?

At the moment I have no way of generating both account types so I can't provide code, but obviously it would help to know if this is even possible first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as a bank account supports ACH transactions, it doesn't matter to Dwolla whether the bank account is intended for for-profit or non-profit use.  You should be able to add both kinds of funding sources to a single Dwolla account.